# Logic for reverse search result

Tags: search

I have a usecase where for a given result value i want to reverse lookup all the search conditions defined that will give this as result.

So, I have a set of search conditions defined in a table as key value list. Each entry in this table is a search query. Now, I have a random value in dataset which can be result of any search entries defined in the table. I want to lookup that table so that for this value i can get all the search queries possible where this value would appear as its result. 
The search table consist of fields search_conditions, search_table among other fields. 
Schema would be like
Search_Table
id (long)
search_table_id (long)
search_conditions (json array as text)

This is value of one such search condition

```
[
{
"key": "name",
"operator": "equals",
"value": "jeff"
},
{
"key": "age",
"operator": "between",
"value": [
  20,
  40
]
}
]
```

Value that i have to search can be say a random user {"name": "mr x", "age":12}.

This may not be exactly a technology based question but its solution may require technology. Any help will be appreciated. The concern is more about optimization as this has to be done in real time.

Comment: So what's your Q exactly? What have you tried? What issues did you encounter? You should post your code so we can better help.

Comment: Perhaps, a loop over the table of "search conditions" testing each entry it it matches the given result, would list the "search entries" that match that result and give you what you want? Could you more clearly define what the structure of a result is and how the set of search conditions is matched against them?

Comment: i have made an edit to question.